# How many kids can I have?

Tags: virtual-families-2

I have three kids right now, but I want to have more. Can I only have three? Every time I bring my parents together, they only argue.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Virtual Families Wikia](http://virtualfamilies.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_have_a_baby_in_Virtual_Families), the maximum number of children you can have is six.

Comment: Alright so I had sixteen kids for some reason.Then I had another family that only had six and another that only lets me have six but my first family like I said had sixteen btw they both said definitely for having kids.So only when they both are super young and definitely both want kids then u can have them 

Comment: We had 10 children in one generation

Answer (score 1):

[image]
I have had nine children, but I’m not sure of how many children you can have.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).